Token and Session is getting undefined in Next auth
I am building a credentials-based authentication module in Next.js using the next-auth library. Everything seems to be working fine. When I try to inject token with some extra information from user, it is getting undefined.
Here is the code for CredentialsProvider:
import { connectToDb } from "@/lib/db";
import { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import prisma from "../../../../../prisma";
import bcryptjs from 'bcryptjs'

const options: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req): Promise<any> {
                await connectToDb();
                console.log(credentials?.email, credentials?.password)
                const user = await prisma.user.findMany({
                    where: {
                        email: credentials?.email,
                    }
                })

                if (!user || !user[0]) {
                    throw new Error("User not found")
                }

                const validPassword = await bcryptjs.compare(credentials?.password as string, user[0].password)
                if (!validPassword) {
                    throw new Error("Invalid password")
                }


                return user;
            }
        })
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt"
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            console.log("jwt callback", user)
            if (user) {
                console.log("user", user)
                token.id = user.id as string
                token.role = user.role;
            }

            console.log("Token obect", token)

            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user.id = token.id as string;
            session.user.role = token.role as string;
            console.log("session callback", session)
            return session
        }
    },

}

export { options }

When I try to console.log both token and session, it shows undefined. Someone please help me with this.
